# How to combine multiple IRedisTypedTransaction<T> in ServiceStack RedisClient

Tags: redis, servicestack

I'm trying to achieve transactional StoreRelatedEntities. So I need to access RedisClient from ITypedRedisClient or this:

```
using (var trans1 = redis.As<X>().CreateTransaction())
using (var trans2=  redis.As<Y>().CreateTransaction())
{
   .....
   trans1.Join(trans2); // :) Fantasy
   trans2.Commit(); 
}
```

Is it proper way? Or I have to

```
using (var trans1=redis.As<X>().CreateTransaction())
{
  trans.QueueCommand(p => ((RedisClient)((RedisTypedClient<T>)p).NativeClient).AddRangeToList(.....);
}
```

Or I have to?

```
using (var trans=redis.CreateTransaction())
{
   trans.QueueCommand(p=>p.As<X>()....); // Casting to Typed RedisClient in Command
   trans.QueueCommand(p=>p.As<Y>()....);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the easiest, so it would be my pick:

```
using (var trans=redis.CreateTransaction())
{
   trans.QueueCommand(p=>p.As<X>()....); // Casting to Typed RedisClient in Command
   trans.QueueCommand(p=>p.As<Y>()....);
}
```

But there's no right/wrong, way just do whatever you're more comfortable with. Each client either inherits or contains an instance of the RedisNativeClient which encapsulates a tcp socket connection with the Redis server. The relationship between the different classes are below:

- **RedisNativeClient** implements [IRedisNativeClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisNativeClient.cs)
- **RedisClient** inherits **RedisNativeClient**, implements [IRedisClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/IRedisClient.cs)
- **RedisTypedClient** implements [IRedisTypedClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Interfaces/Redis/Generic/IRedisTypedClient.cs)

  - Contains instance of **RedisClient** accessible via [RedisClient](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Redis/Generic/RedisTypedClient.cs#L36) property

Comment: RedisTypedClient has RedisClient but IRedisTypedClient does not have IRedisClient (NativeClient).. Do you plan to add it ?

Comment: send a pull-request and I'll consider it :)

Comment: There's now a RedisClient property on IRedisTypedClient